# Deprecated Registry alternate using session or any other possibilities for 'Custom module'

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, registry, deprecated

In my case, I created Blog Module and in that while getting **`current_blog_post`** from URL's id, I **`register`** it in coreRegistry and use **`registry`** to get the value in various places.

1. **`register`** is used in Controller to get the current id while editing the form.
   The below code is Located in

   > myVendor/myModule/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Edit.php

[image]

2. Similarly, the registered value is called through **`registry`** in various place such as

[image]

**Question**: Is there any other way instead of using the **`registry`** as it is deprecated?

**Note**: I referred in many places including [atwix](https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/) and in that they showed to get the values by the registry which are already registered by the core. In my case, I am using **`register`** and getting the registered value using **`registry`**.